# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The parser has encountered more than "64 000" entity expansions in this document

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am parsing large XML(72MB-170K entries) file using SAX XML parser:

```
SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();

//THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR
saxParser.parse(new File("JMdict"), handler);
// Get entries list
List<Entry> entryList = handler.getEmpList();
// print entry information
for (Entry ent : entryList)
    System.out.println(ent);
```

Error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The parser has encountered more than
>   "64 000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed
>   by the application.

How to limit SAX parser entries(for example to 1000 entries)?

Comment: [Java Tutorial: JAXP: Processing Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by setting EntityExpansionLimit

```
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager mgr = new org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager();
    mgr.setEntityExpansionLimit(1000000);
    saxParser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/security-manager", mgr);
    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();

    // THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR
    saxParser.parse(new File("JMdict"), handler);
    // Get entries list
    List<Entry> entryList = handler.getEmpList();
    // print entry information
    for (Entry ent : entryList)
        System.out.println(ent);
```